# Simplest way for an image to pop up, like an image gallery portfolio, lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox, image-gallery

I'm just looking for the simplest way for my image to pop up / zoom in etc. (if that's the correct term), but pop up and take the space of the existing screen or device, like a lightbox. Basically I'm just creating a very simple image gallery. And on click, image will pop up.

I've seen a couple of tutorials and templates but I'm not really a super coder and I'm trying my best to create this on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to using pure css or include jquery too. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be great.

My code is here (I can't seem to paste the css, sorry):

http://codepen.io/anthonydda/pen/NGVoZN

```
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
         <ul class="picture">
             <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"><li>
             <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"><li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

.container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.picture {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Hello Anthony, we cannot suggest a tool for you to use, this is out of SO standards. You can check for something popular and effective, try to use it, then if you fail show us what you have done and we'll be glad to help. There are tons of examples and plugins out there.

Comment: You sound like the perfect candidate to just use a plugin. Is the intention that you want to build your own? Or are you just looking for something that will work? If you just need it to work, get a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple little trick you can fiddle with:

`img:active { position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1; height: 100%; width:auto }`

Add to your CSS and click on the images. It will grow to 100% `height` and adjusts `width` accordingly. `z-index: 1` moves it on top of the rest of the page.

Try this with `img:hover` too. Start easy, learn and extend to your needs.

With `img:hover { transform: scale(1.25 }` you can simply attract attention when ppl hover over an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codepen I created for you:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meYoWy

Above your "container" class, I added a div with a lightbox class and another div inside it for the image container.

```
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

I created a lightbox css class to dim the background and when clicked, it will close the zoomed image.

```
.lightbox {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.lightbox .image {
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  top: 5%;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I used JQuery to manipulate the dom elements and to use fadein and fadeout animations and to bind events to the image.

```
$('ul.picture li').on('click', function() {
  var img = $(this).find('img'); //get the image element inside the li
  var imgsrc = img.attr('src'); //get the source url of the image
  $('.lightbox > .image').css('background-image','url("'+imgsrc+'")') //use the src of the image to use as the background of the .image div inside lightbox
  $('.lightbox').fadeIn('fast'); //show the lightbox
})

$('.lightbox').on('click', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut('fast'); //close the lightbox when clicked
})

$('.lightbox > .image').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  /*
  this code was added to prevent the image from closing 
  when the image is clicked instead of the lightbox
  */
})
```